# Matching a pair of foreign keys in MySQL/SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, rdbms

Is there a way to pair foreign keys to match?

E.g. The `user_id` and `subs_id` fk pair doesn't match in the product table but was allowed to be added.

Table: user

```
| user_id (PK) | first_name  | last_name  |
| -------------| ------------|------------|
| 000001       | David       | Hawk       |
| 000002       | Ali         | Abdullah   |
```

Table: subscription

```
| user_id (FK) | subs_id (PK) | subs_status | total_cycles |
| -------------| -------------|-------------|--------------|
| 000001       | ABC_123456   | ACTIVE      | 4            |
| 000002       | CDE_654321   | CANCELLED   | 8            |
```

Table: product

```
| user_id (FK) | subs_id (FK)   |   product   |  plan  | product-key (PK) |
| -------------| ---------------|-------------|--------|------------------|
| **000001**   | **CDE_654321** | Product-A   | Pro    | A5CD-8Z62-X2D4   |
| **000002**   | **ABC_123456** | Product-B   | Plus   | WFE7-71W4-Z64D   |
```

Comment: Made a simple design error there. There should be no `user_id` in the `product` table. There should only be one product row per product. With your design you would need one product row per each user that subscribed.

Comment: Also there should be no `subs_id` in the product row, for the same basic reason. Your `subscriptions` table is basically a link table between User and Product

Comment: You dont need user_id column in product. You can use the subs_id and get the user id associated to the subscription

Comment: Also I would place the `product_key` which appears to be specific to a single users subscription to a product into the subscriptions table and make an `id` column the PK and AutoIncrement

Comment: Whatever you are trying to say, you are not saying it. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. [ask] [mre] [Help]

Comment: @RiggsFolly The `subscription` table is being used for storing data from REST API calls while the `product_id` is actually a UUID generated by server-side. I'd rather not mixed it up. I think I'll go with @ShreyasPrakash suggestion, I see his point about `user_id` being redundant. I just designed it like that for ease of use I suppose, so that I can make direct query using either `subs_id` or `user_id`. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have two foreign keys, one on the `user_id` and one on the `subs_id`. Instead, you need to have a single foreign key on the combination of the two:

```sql
ALTER TABLE product
ADD CONSTRAINT prodcut_subscription_fk
FOREIGN KEY (user_id, subs_id)
REFERENCES subscription(user_id, subs_id)
```

Comment: It worked. I set up the `user_id` FK from `user` table then `subs_id` from the `subscription` table. Funny how it doesn't have the same effect. I've changed the design to only use `susb_id` but this is good info. Thanks.